# Ayuda con cron para hacer backup de una bdd MySql

Tags: mysql, windows, cron

Quiero crear una copia de seguridad de mi base de datos (MySql con phpMyAdmin) y he encontrado el siguiente script para poder automatizarlo:

```
echo off
mysqldump -hlocalhost -udb_admin -pContrasenaDb bdd_n1 > 
copia_seguridad_%Date:~6,4%%Date:~3,2%%Date:~0,2%_.sql
exit
```

Esto lo guardo en `.bat` y al ejecutarlo me crea un archivo `.sql` que en teoría almacena toda la información de la base de datos. Digo en teoría porque al ejecutarlo me genera el documento `.sql` pero su contenido está vacío.
El nombre del host (*-h*), el usuario (*-u*), la contraseña (*-p*) y el nombre de la base de datos son correctos ya que son los mismos que uso para conectar la base de datos con mi web (que desarrollo en local con XAMPP).

Alguien sabría decirme qué está mal en el script o sabría algún otro modo de hacer una copia de seguridad automatizada?

Comment: ¿Has intentado ejecutar desde una consola (eg: `cmd`) el comando `mysqldump` y validado que el mismo exista y/o el `path` a éste configurado en las variables de entorno?

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el programa que uso para backup de mi base de datos.

Lo uso en una bd en hosting compartido. Como dices que estás en local, puedes darle más seguridad al script,  guardando las credenciales de conexión en `/root/.my.cnf` y ejecutando el comando de copiado de este modo: `copycmd=/usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy` (dentro del script, lo indico en la parte que iría, en comentario). Si no puedes configurarlo de ese manera, tendrás un warning de seguridad, porque no se recomienda escribir contraseñas de bd en la línea de comandos... no es grave, si un hacker no está escuchando lo que tecleas en tu máquina :)

Puedes almacenar este script en un archivo llamado por ejemplo: `backup_db.sh` lo puedes probar desde la consola y una vez funcionando puedes programar un cron que lo ejecute con la frecuencia que le indiques.

El script da la posibilidad de guardar varias versiones de copia (lo puedes modificar en esta variable `numversions=4`), y agrega la fecha al nombre del archivo de cada copia.

```
#archivo: backup_db.sh


#nombre base de datos (pueden ser  varias, separadas por espacio)
dblist="nombre-base-de-datos"
user="nombre-usuario"
pass="constraseña"

# Directorio para for backups
backupdir=/home/...

# Cantidad de versiones a mantener
numversions=4

# Path para el comando de copiado MySQL 
# Si se ponen las credenciales en  /root/.my.cnf usar el comando comentado en vez del otro
#copycmd=/usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy
copycmd="/usr/bin/mysqldump -u$user -p$pass --lock-tables --databases"

# Crear directorio si es necesario
mkdir -p "$backupdir"
if [ ! -d "$backupdir" ]; then
   echo "Directorio inválido: $backupdir"
   exit 1
fi

# Aquí comienza la copia
echo "Copiando bases de datos MySQL ..."
RC=0
for database in $dblist; do
   echo
   echo "Copiando $database ..."
   mv "$backupdir/$database.gz" "$backupdir/$database.0.gz" 2> /dev/null
   $copycmd $database | gzip > "$backupdir/$database.gz"

   RC=$?
   if [ $RC -gt 0 ]; then
     continue;
   fi

   # Rollover the backup directories
   rm -fr "$backupdir/$database.$numversions.gz" 2> /dev/null
   i=$numversions
   while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do
     mv "$backupdir/$database.`expr $i - 1`.gz" "$backupdir/$database.$i.gz" 2> /dev/null
     i=`expr $i - 1`
   done
done

if [ $RC -gt 0 ]; then
   echo "MySQL Copia fallida!"
   exit $RC
else
   # Copia completada. Lista de versiones de backup!
   ls -l "$backupdir"
   echo "Copia MySQL completa!"
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: El OP usa Windows. El script que está haciendo es un BATCH. Esta respuesta requiere un *nix.

Comment: No me percaté de ese detalle, gracias por la observación @toledano Creo que la pregunta debería llevar la etiqueta `Windows` para evitar confusiones