# MySQL no arranca, base de datos dañada

Tags: mysql, windows, innodb

Tengo datos de una base datos de un cliente, quien estaba usando el software y de repente no funcionó más nada, entonces voy y reviso y de la nada el servicio del motor MySQL se detuvo, trato de arrancarlo de nuevo y nada, trato de ejecutarlo a través de CMD y nada, extraigo entonces la carpeta Data la cual regularmente la vuelco en mi propio MySQL de mi pc donde desarrollo y nada, regularmente al hacer esto arranca sea la carpeta Data que sea, entonces pienso que la base de datos esta dañada.

Dentro de la carpeta data se encuentran las bases de datos por carpeta separada pero no logro hacerlos andar individualmente.

¿Cómo podría recuperar los datos tabla por tabla?

Tengo un respaldo del 09/11/2019 pero la idea es recuperar los datos que se puedan de la base de datos actual e importarlas a este respaldo para actualizarla, ya que la actual no arranca.

Tengo 5 bases de datos separados:

- administraciom_2
- productos_2
- ventas_2
- contabilidad_2
- rentabilidad_2

y otras bases de datos propias de mysql

La versión del mysql es la 5.6.24 win32

Las tablas se guardan en archivos con extensión `.frm` y `.lbd`

He intentado copiar esos archivos individualmente después de reinstalar el mysql y crear una base de datos vacía y tratar de arrancar pero otra vez se cierra el motor, mysqld.exe. Al parecer no es tan simple

Mi pc tiene 8gb de ram. la carpeta data pesa unos 400mb.

EDIT:
En ninguna de las dos pc inicia el servicio cuando vuelco la carpeta Data en mysql, regularmente inicia con cualquier carpeta Data de cualquiera de mis clientes, ahora estoy usando mi pc que es de desarrollo. Tengo muchos clientes con el mismo soft, cuando necesito corregir algo del soft copio la carpeta Data la en mi mysql inicio el servicio y uso. Eso no sucede porque en la pc de mi cliente ya no arrancaba el servicio mysql, en mi pc de desarrollo tampoco arranca, la base de datos ya estaba dañada, lo que impide que inicie el servicio, pero tengo todos los archivos .frm e .idb

Comment: Vale, un placer intentar ayudar :D Espero que logres solucionar pronto el problema

Comment: Acabo de encontrar la solución! hay que hacer una serie de pasos tabla por tabla añadiendolas, que incluye ir añadiendo el archivo .idb con el motor encendido, con las bases de datos y tablas creadas en blanco, pero usando la sentencias "ALTER TABLE table_name DISCARD TABLESPACE" . se copia el archivo .idb en la carpeta data\nombre de base de datos y después se "importa" por decirlo asi con "ALTER TABLE table_Name IMPORT TABLESPACE". Habia sido que mysql guarda la estructura de tablas en formato .frm y los datos en formato .idb, se puede descartar e importar con la sentencia DISCARD e IMPORT

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Entonces, en la parte inferior de esta página hay un textarea cuyo título dice "Tu Respuesta", agrega los pasos que has realizado, serás el héroe de más usuarios/visitantes con la misma situación y/o algo parecido. Luego de 24 horas recuerda marcar la respuesta como aceptada, así estarás ayudando a la buena salud del sitio :D

Comment: Dale muchas gracias! en seguida redacto correctamente la respuesta, estoy todavía recuperando tabla por tabla la base de datos

Comment: Igual es un poco tarde pero si las tablas están corruptas hay una utilidad para recuperarlas

Comment: si, es que ya importe todas las tablas y el server crashea al hacer una consulta en la tabla "detalles" de la base de datos ventas_2 que es donde se guardan los detalles de las ventas, ahora la estoy analizando con el Mysql GUI tools, estoy haciendo un checkeo de la tabla. De todas formas podrias decirme que herramienta usas para analizar la tabla?

Comment: El peor error de todo esto es que tengas un respaldo del 29 de noviembre. Establece una política de backups con una frecuencia adecuada según la cantidad de veces que las tablas son modificadas: si muchas veces al día, un copia diaria, si pocas veces a la semana, uno o dos backups por semana, si queda 15 días un backup quincenal, etc. Para ganar en rapidez y seguridad conviene programar el backup vía ssh. [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/87382/29967). Luego, se manda a ejecutar el archivo en un cron.

Comment: Exacto, estoy trabajando en eso, lamentablemente tu respuesta no me sirve ya mi aplicación es para windows y usa mysql a secas, el motor solo, no es nada basado en web, solo se conecta por ODBC,Estoy viendo algo para hacer con google drive, pero comprimir la base de datos completa y guardar la carpeta en la nube todos los dias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Base de datos: MySQL 5.6.24 tipo InnoDB**

***Se contaba con respaldo de la carpeta física `Data` de unos meses anteriores que se uso como base para importar las tablas de base de datos actual dañada**

Disculpen el inconveniente, efectivamente al estar dañada la base de datos el motor no va a arrancar. El problema que tiene la base de datos es irreparable por lo que como última alternativa fue tratar de importar tabla por tabla en otra base de datos nueva, o en este caso como tenia un respaldo de un par de meses atrás, lo que hice fue tomar esa como base e ir borrando e importando tabla por tabla las que si se podían leer.

**Se probaron diversas herramientas para ver si se podía reparar la tabla dañada pero sin éxito, los datos estaban corruptos**.

El procedimiento es básicamente ir volcando los archivos de las tablas `.idb` en la carpeta correspondiente a la base de datos, por lo que es necesario tener un respaldo o tener la base de datos físicamente, todo en formato de archivos, preferentemente la carpeta completa **Data** o en algunos casos puede aparecer como **Lib**.

Para realizar el volcado primero es necesario tener ya una base de datos armada con la misma estructura de **tablas-campos** a la que se quiera volcar los archivos `.idb`, esto se puede hacer en tiempo real con el motor andando con la base de datos básica o de respaldo que se tenga que funcione, que por lo menos tenga la estructura de **tablas-campos** funcionando.

Hay que entender que parte del trabajo se hace con consultas **SQL**, y parte manipulando archivos por lo que es necesario tener acceso a los archivos físicos del servidor **MySQL**, que si se instalara individualmente, estaría ubicado en la carpeta `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6` o algo similar.

En mi caso, dentro de la carpeta de **MySQL Server 5.6** hay una carpeta llamada **Data** donde se guardan todos los datos, configurada así por el `my.ini` que guarda la configuración, puede ser distinto para otras instalaciones del servidor.

Una vez que tenemos en cuenta estos datos, ya podremos arrancar el proceso (el **Server MySQL** debe estar funcionando aunque sea con una base de datos básica de la misma estructura **tabla-campos**).

Cada base de datos se guarda en una carpeta aparte dentro de la carpeta **Data**, entonces, si tenemos una base de datos que se llama **administracion_2** como es en mi caso, entonces, habrá una carpeta **administracion_2** dentro de la carpeta **Data**.

Una vez tengamos el server arrancado, ya es necesario acceder al mismo por medio de alguna herramienta o algo que permita hacer consultas **SQL**, en mi caso uso el **MySQL Administrator** que viene en el paquete de **MySQL GUI Tools**. Y con esto solo queda ir eliminando los datos de las tablas e importando los nuevos con el siguiente procedimiento, tabla por tabla:

1) Ir a la carpeta de la base de datos, en mi caso `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\Data\administracion_2\`

2) En esta carpeta de la base de datos hay dos archivos por tabla, uno en formato `.frm` que guarda la estructura de la tabla, y otro en formato `.idb` que guarda los datos en formato **InnoDB**, aunque la tabla esté vacía, este archivo igual existirá y tendrá datos dentro.

3) Abrir el ejecutor de consultas **MySQL** a mano, puede ser el **MySQL Administrator**, **MySQL Workbench**, etc.

4) Eliminar los **datos** de la tabla vacía, valga la incoherencia porque aunque esté vacía **MySQL** la tiene cargada y en memoria, se borra con la instrucción SQL `ALTER TABLE table_name DISCARD TABLESPACE` en **"table_name"** va el nombre de la tabla, la cual también se refleja en el nombre del archivo `.idb`. En mi caso `actividades`. La que inmediatamente al ejecutar ese comando **SQL** ***borrará*** el archivo `.idb` correspondiente a la tabla, en mi caso el comando `ALTER TABLE àdministracion_2.actividades DISCARD TABLESPACE` ***borrará*** el archivo `actividades.idb`.

5) Se copia el archivo que se quiere volcar, que corresponda a la tabla, en la carpeta de la base de datos, en mi caso `actividades.idb` dentro de `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\Data\administracion_2\`

6) Se importa esos datos con el comando SQL `ALTER TABLE table_Name IMPORT TABLESPACE` en mi caso **"table_name"** es **actividades**.  La que inmediatamente al ejecutar ese comando **SQL** ***importará*** el archivo recién copiado `.idb` correspondiente a la tabla, en mi caso el comando `ALTER TABLE àdministracion_2.actividades IMPORT TABLESPACE` ***importará*** el archivo `actividades.idb`.

NOTA: No confundirse, los archivos de las tablas deben copiarse con el mismo nombre de la **tabla.idb**, en mi caso **actividades.idb** al mismo lugar donde el **MySQL** los borró al ejecutar los comando `ALTER TABLA table_name DISCARD TABLESPACE`, sino, **MySQL** no podrá importar, no encontrará el archivo de los datos nuevos a importar.

**Se repite el procedimiento tabla por tabla, la única tabla que no se pudo actualizar/recuperar es la dañada, el resto de la base de datos si se pudo, tomando una base de datos anterior, e importando tabla por tabla de base de datos actual dañada**.

**Saludos!**

Comment: simplemente un consejo: hazte un script por si te vuelve a pasar

Comment: Totalmente, es un dilema que tengo, no se bien como implementarlo, regularmente hago una por semana de forma externa, porque tambien si se daña el disco y tenes los respaldos internos tambien no sirve, estoy evaluando seriamente instalar un disco externo a todos mis clientes y usar el software SyncBackFree y que vaya guardando un espejo de la base, pero si se daña la base principal, la va a espejar dañado y todo, a google drive no me conviene subir dia por dia porque la base de algunos clientes llega a pesar unos 1,5 gb otros 400 mb, y se complica, debo armar nomas algo que guarde por fechas

Comment: algo externo que guarde por fechas la carpeta Data del mysql comprimido, supongo que se solucionaría, pero es trabajo y configuración para todos mis clientes osea para todos los sistemas